# How to find the last commit that was not done by me?

Tags: git

I want to squash my commits using `git rebase -i HEAD~n`, but in order to do so, I typically have to do `git log` and manually count all the number of commits up to the next commit that was not made by me. In other words I would see something like this

```
commit 89073409kiejroijer
Author: AlanH
commit 89073409kiejroijer12903
Author: AlanH
...
commit 89073409kiejroijer83
Author: AlanH
commit 890789754239kldjrjsafd
Author: JohnSmith
```

So I would count all the ones before John's commit. Then do `git rebase -i HEAD~n`

Is there a way to just do this in one step so that I don't have to count my commits?

Comment: If you are using a tracking branch just specify '@{u}' instead of HEAD~N and it will do what you want automagically.

Comment: If you've got a tracking branch you don't even need that, it's the default: `git rebase` will do it.

Comment: @AndrewC Does the `u` stand for username? Or do you mean literally `@{u}`?

Comment: Literally, @{u} is shorthand for upstream, so if you are tracking origin/master it means origin/master, if you are tracking origin/some_branch it means origin/some_branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --author="Adam" --invert-grep -n1
```

gives the first commit that didn't match Author="Adam"

use that `<commit-id>` to rebase

```
git rebase -i <commit-id>
```

Comment: Great find!  Not gonna get better than this.  Maybe add `--format=%H` to just give the commit id.

Comment: @jthill so would the entire command be: `git log --author="Adam" --invert-grep -n1 --format=%H
`

Answer (score 1):

No need to count, just use the commit id you want, in your example you can see it's `890789754239kldjrjsafd`.

To find it programmatically the searches in the other answers will work, the easiest search I can find is

```
git log --format=%h\ %an|awk '!/ Your Name/{print $1;exit}'
```

Comment: `n` should be an integer though, how can it take a commit ID?

Comment: Replace the whole thing, git just translates `HEAD~n` to the commit id anyway, just give it directly.

Answer (score 0):

use below shell can fix your issue.

```
git log | cat | grep Author | awk -F: "{print $1}" | grep -v "yourname" | wc -l
```

this command counts the commit numbers before your last commit.

then use `git rebase -i HEAD~n`

or use this in one command.

```
git log | cat | grep Author | awk -F: "{print $1}" | grep -v "yourname" | wc -l | xargs -I {} git rebase -i HEAD~{}
```

hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
git log --format='%H %an' | grep -v Adam | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 git log -1
```

Where `Adam` is name of the author i.e. you